# Float calculation always off by 1

Tags: python

according to my book inputting 5 and 6.5 into this function should return
73.6901. I keep getting 72.6901 though. I know the formula is perfect, I can't imagine what else it could be. Is there a certain degree of inaccuracy with floats that could be causing this logic error?

```
import math

def area(n, side):
    area= (n * (side * side))/(
        4 * math.tan(math.pi/n))
    return area

def main():

    sideNumber = int(input("Enter the number of sides :"))
    sideLength = float(input("Enter the side: "))


    print("The area of the polygon is %f" %(area(sideNumber, sideLength)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: No, something that is off exactly by 1 like that is very unlikely to be a floating point error.  It's more likely a typo in the book.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's a typo in the book. I just transcribed a different formula for the same thing from [mathwords](http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_regular_polygon.htm):

```
def area2(n, side):
    r = 0.5 * side * (math.cos(math.pi / n) / math.sin(math.pi / n))
    return n * r * r * math.tan(math.pi / n)
```

And I also get 72.690170 .

Comment: Your reason is perfect but your _different formula_ is simply validating `sin(n)/cos(n) = tan(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is 72.6901 and your book probably has a typo.

Floating point inaccuracy shouldn't be that large. Usually its only going to matter many decimal places after the dot.